# How to invoke the same browser instance from a web link

Tags: html, browser, hyperlink

I have a link on my web page. When I click it I open a new window and show content in that window.

I would like to be able, in a second time, to click again in that link and, instead of opening a new browser window/tab, to get the previous instance and put content on it.

Is it possible in some way?

Thanks in advance, greetings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTML you do this by specifying a named target:

```
<a href="page2.html" target="myotherwindow">Link 2</a>
<a href="page3.html" target="myotherwindow">Link 3</a>
<a href="page4.html" target="myotherwindow">Link 4</a>
```

All will open in the same window.

*Note:* If the user has their preferences set to open new windows in tabs, these will all reference the same tab (vs. window)

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know it ! But when i click the second time (in Firefox) content is loaded in the new tab but it remains hidden, is it normal?

Comment: Correct, it changes the content but does not assign focus.  If you want to do that, you'll need to use the JavaScript `window.open(url,name,features);` method.  When you assign a name, you can then later give it focus... e.g. create the popup `window.open('page3.html', 'myotherwindow','statusbar=yes');` load new content... `myotherwindow.document.location.href = 'page4.hmtl';` then (re)set the focus `myotherwindow.focus();`

Comment: Great, my friend, you're the man !!
I've made 

my_win=window.open('page.html','mywindow');
if(my_win!=null)
     my_win.focus();

Thank you very much!!